# Error : "No router instance found. You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**can any one help to solve this problem : **
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGw8H.jpg)

and this is the code :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PZef.jpg)

I tried to make a theme switcher in next JS that when I click a button the theme will change but when I click the button the error appears and I haven't find the solution.

Comment: Please add code for theme switcher by updating the question, the imports statements are missing in images. *(Please paste the code, images of code aren't helpful because we it makes difficult to suggests changes at various lines).*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> *I tried to make a theme switcher in next JS that when I click a button the theme will change but when I click the button the error appears and I haven't find the solution ...*

**Possible Causes :**

- theme switcher component needs to be marked as Client-side component because it has onClick event,
- You can't use `useRouter` from `next/router` in app router, (its for pages router, and you are using app router, `src/app/...`).

**Solution :**

- First make theme switcher component as client-side component, by adding this line at the top of this file

> `'use client'`

- Then import `useRouter()` from `import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'`

**Please Read :**

- **Client Components :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components
- **Benefits of Client Rendering / When to use client side components :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#benefits-of-client-rendering
- **Server and Client Composition Patterns :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns
- **useRouter (from App Router):** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router
- **useRouter (from Pages Router) :** https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router
- **Using Client Components in Next.js Example :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#using-client-components-in-nextjs

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment.***